# Convert Dictionary Unequal Items to Data-frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary that has 3000 keys and each key has a list as its value,

example:

```
dictionary = {'yup': ['chocolate', 'pizza', 'rainbows'], 'tape': ['what', 'milk'], ....}
```

I want to convert this dictionary into a database but since I have unequal values I am unable to use the pandas command "`pd.DataFrame(dictionary)`". I received the error message "arrays must all be same length".

My question is, how do I still create a data frame (transpose it) and have the empty cells where there isn't data.

Example:

```
index   column1      column2   column3 

`'yup'  'chocolate'  'pizza'    'rainbows`'

'tape'  'what'       'milk'     blank
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `values` for values and `keys` for index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dictionary.values()), index=dictionary.keys())

        0           1       2
yup     chocolate   pizza   rainbows
tape    what        milk    None
```

If need the column named `index`

```
df.reset_index()

    index   0           1       2
0   yup     chocolate   pizza   rainbows
1   tape    what        milk    None
```

Answer (score 2):

Transform your values to `pd.Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k:pd.Series(v) for k,v in dictionary.items()}).T

              0      1         2
tape       what   milk       NaN
yup   chocolate  pizza  rainbows
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k:pd.Series(v) for k,v in dictionary.items()},orient='index')

              0      1         2
tape       what   milk       NaN
yup   chocolate  pizza  rainbows
```